# Install shapely windows using pip

Tags: shapely, pip

My question is related to 
[Why is Shapely not installing correctly?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62925/why-is-shapely-not-installing-correctly)

However it is not working and I am struggling to find information/understand how to install it. 
I am running my own environment using venv.

I have downloaded the binary correct to my Windows architecture (64-bit) and python version (3.7.3) from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely.
My pip version is updated to last version (pip-19.0.3).
I have placed the file in the root of my app where I am running my venv from.

In my cmd terminal I am trying

```
pip install Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

But this just give me

```
ERROR: Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try installing the gdal wheel 1st from the download page you posted

Comment: how many pythons do you have ?

Comment: I am running my terminal using my python instance of my venv so that should be fine? Unfortunately gdal failed as well.. Was trying python -m pip install GDAL-2.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl but failed with the saem error as with shapely. Will do more research on that though

Comment: @geogrow try installing shapely using pip3, and check your `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` variables, they should be refering to where you python 3.7 is

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go!

Comment: Navigate to python folder (which includes `python.exe`) in cmd and try to run `python -m pip install shapely`.

Answer (score 1):

From a Windows command prompt with Python, you can now install Shapely like this:

```
pip install shapely
```

this will download and install the binary wheels from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) for Windows, macOS or Linux.

Comment: Do you know if they recently uploaded to PyPI? I'm pretty sure that Shapely versions < 1.7 were not on there and therefore supposed to be installed the way OP is trying to. At the time of asking a pip install might not have been possible. Glad it's been added though.

Comment: @TimSkovJacobsen correct this was not possible at the time of the question. Pip for Windows started with Shapely 1.7.0+ and Python 3.5.